# Difference between LabelFor and DisplayFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to know exactly when to use `@Html.DisplayFor` and when to use `@Html.LabelFor` in MVC.

Everytime I work on them, it confuses me.

Comment: `LabelFor` displays the properties name and is associated with a control (input, select etc) in a form. `DisplayFor` renders the value of a property

Comment: Also, `DisplayFor` will try to use a [display template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), if you have one defined.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you should write an answer, as you're absolutely correct

Answer (score 11, accepted):

suppose you have a property model like this:

```
[Display("Name:")]
public string Name{ get; set;}
```

and you need to show in your view like this:

Name: Mohammad

Then you can do this:

```
@HTML.LabelFor(m => m.Name)// this will show "Name:"
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)// this will show (read only) "Mohammad"
```

Comment: You have it the wrong way around (`LabelFor()` will output "Name" and `DisplayFor()` will output "Mohammad")

Answer (score 0):

Also, `LabelFor` will be clickable if used with a `CheckBox`, etc where `DisplayFor` will not.